# make the error send in channel instead of the console so the program wont stop running

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, discord.js, unique-index

I am currently having a problem about my signup command and when  searched about the error I am having which is:
`MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ShinDB.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: "Shin" }`

they always say to drop the collection which I don't want.

what i want is for example i wrote `'>signup Shin thisisatest@1234'` and if the `'Shin'` username is already in the username database it will NOT send the `'MongoServerError'` in the console but instead it will send an error `'That username already exist'` in the channel which the user send it to.

**Signup Command:**

```js
var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{14,})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\\W).*$", "g");
var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.{10,})(((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))).*$", "g");
var enoughRegex = new RegExp("(?=.{8,}).*", "g");
var specialChar = /[`!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
const User = require('../../Database/models/user')

module.exports = {
    name: "signup",
    description: "Signup for an Economy Account",
    usage: ">signup",
    aliases: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        //message is inguild
        if (message.inGuild()) {
            return message.reply({ content: `This command can only be used in <@${client.user.id}> DM.\n\`\`Usage: >signup <username> <password>\`\`\n\`\`Note: Your Economy Account is Safe\`\`` })
        }

        //message is in DM
        if (message.channel.type === 'DM') {
            
            // USERNAME
            const userargs = args[0]
            const pass = args[1]

            if (!userargs) {
                return message.reply({ content: '**Please provide a username for your Economy Account!\n``Correct Usage: >signup <username> <password>``**' })
            }

            const userToLow = userargs.toLowerCase()
            const user = userToLow.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + userToLow.substring(1, userToLow.length)
            
            if (user.length < 3) return message.reply({ content: '**[__Too Short__]** **Your Username must have atleast 3 Characters**' })
            if (user.length > 7) return message.reply({ content: '**[__Too Long__]** **You Username must only have 7 Characters**' })
            if (specialChar.test(user)) {
                return message.reply({ content: '**Username\'s must not have any Special Characters**' })
            }

            // PASSWORD
            let str
            let med
            let weak
            if (strongRegex.test(pass)) {
                str = 'Strong'
            }
            if (mediumRegex.test(pass)) {
                med = 'Medium'
            }
            if (!strongRegex.test(pass) && !mediumRegex.test(pass)) {
                weak = 'Weak'
            }

            if (!pass) return message.reply({ content: '**Please provide a password for your Economy Account!**' })
            if (pass.length < 8) return message.reply({ content: '**[__Too Short__]** **Your Password must have atleast 8 Characters**' })

            // CREATING THE ACCOUNT
            User.findOne({ createdBy: message.author.id }, async (err, data) => {
                if (data) {
                    return message.reply({ content: `**You already have made an Account and the Username of the Account that you made is: \`\`${data.username}\`\`\n\`\`Note: if you forget your password you can just run the command >recoveraccount\`\`**` })
                } else if (err) {
                    return message.reply({ content: 'That username already exist' })
                } else {
                    new User({
                        loggedInOn: "0",
                        createdBy: message.author.id,
                        isLoggedIn: false,
                        username: user,
                        password: pass,
                    }).save()
                    return message.reply({ content: 'You have successfuly made an Economy Account!'})
                }

            })

        }
    }
}
```

**User Schema/Model:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    loggedInOn: String,
    createdBy: String,
    isLoggedIn: Boolean,
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
```

**Full Error:**

```js
                return callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(res.writeErrors[0]));
                                ^

MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: ShinDB.users index: username_1 dup key: { username: "Shin" }
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:53:33
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:273:25
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:327:20)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:215:9)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Shinomy\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10) {
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { username: 1 },
  keyValue: { username: 'Shin' },
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

**My Database Current Collections:**

[Collections Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o5c4.png)

i hope i have explained it very well, any help would be really appreciated. thanks.

Comment: You can catch (`try-catch`) the E11000 duplicate key error, verify the error code (`11000`) and return appropriate message. This is possible in NodeJS code.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: By learning some Javascript, if you working on js you should know try-catch blocks.

Comment: i know try-catch blocks, but i mean how do i verify the error code 11000?

Comment: Console.log error on catch block and look what you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your bot instance shutting down use the following:

```
client.on('error', (error) => {
console.error(error)
// You can also put your "error message" create here
})
```

Along with that. Whatever you're doing with your MongoDB code is very "jank". The following will likely fix it.

```
User.findOne({ createdBy: message.author.id }).then((data) => {
  if (data) {
    return message.reply({
      content: `**You already have made an Account and the Username of the Account that you made is: \`\`${data.username}\`\`\n\`\`Note: if you forget your password you can just run the command >recoveraccount\`\`**`,
    });
  } else if (!data) {
    User.findOne({ username: user }).then((findUsername) => {
      if (findUsername) {
        return message.reply('There is already an account with that username!')
      } else {
        new User({
          loggedInOn: '0',
          createdBy: message.author.id,
          isLoggedIn: false,
          username: user,
          password: pass,
        }).save();
        return message.reply({ content: 'You have successfuly made an Economy Account!' });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hello, what about case sensitive username? For example i wrote "-signup Shin testpass1234", it would go into the database but if i tried, "-signup sHin pass1234", it would also go into the database, how do i prevent this?

Comment: Convert all usernames to lowercase, don’t allow them to be “cased”. To do that you should just have to replace `user` to `user.toLowerCase()` in the DB code above

Comment: i've seen other website like, when i signup my name as 'Shin', and tried to signup 'shin/shIn/ShIN', it gives me an error that its already signed up, even though the usernames is cased, how do i do this?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're saying. But, what I've posted above, should fix people being able to get usernames that are already taken in other "cases"

Comment: oh sorry I've misread it, so what am i supposed to do to not let people get usernames that are already taken in other cases? i just dont want usernames in `toLowerCase()`